# error MSB3073: The command ""..\..\..\..\lib\Tests.exe" :VCEnd" exited with code -1073740940

Tags: c++

I am getting the above message when I build my code.

Can anyone please throw some light on this issue and help me?

Many thanks

Best Regards

Chintan

Updated question: The above error occurs for the following piece of code.

```
vector <double> vBandSubset (vBand.size(), 0.0); 
vBandSubset = vBand; 
double dMeanBand=GetMean(vBand); 
int j = 0; 
for (int i = nBin1 - 3; i <= nBin1 + 3; i++) 
{ 
    vBandSubset[i] = dMeanBand*(1 + 0.00001*j); 
    j++; 
}
```

Comment: Try a right click on VS(I assume?) and run as administrator. Then, rebuild your project. Let me know!

Comment: I am running VS as administrator. Do I need to provide more information? But I am not sure what else I can do. Thanks again.

Comment: You can provide source code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the details about what exactly you are doing it's hard to say anything with certainty, but -1073740940 == 0xC0000374 == STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION. Does it shed any light?

**[UPD]** Assuming the interpretation of the error value as an NTSTATUS was correct, you are corrupting your heap. Further assuming that it happens in the code you shown, it's most probable that either `nBin1 < 3` or `nBin1 + 3 >= vBandSubset.size()`. In either of those cases your assignment in the loop will overwrite technical heap areas before or after the `vBandSubset` data block.

Since it's a test, I suggest you use `vBandSubset.at(i)` instead of `vBandSubset[i]`. Unlike `operator[]`, `at()` validates its argument and will throw an exception if it's invalid. An exception is much easier to debug than memory corruption.

PS. You can edit your question and put the code there. It's more convenient for readers that way.